# Route using underscores instead of spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4.0. I have a 'Specialty' model that 'admins' can modify using the standard resource routes. However there is also a separate consumer facing controller that is used to display those 'Specialties' in a pretty fashion. As such I have the following routes:

```
get "specialty/:name" => "site#specialty", as: :site_specialty
resources :specialties
```

The site#specialty controller action is as follows:

```
def specialty
  @specialty = Specialty.find_by_name(params[:name])
end
```

This results in urls like the following percent escaped routes:

```
/specialty/project%20management
```

I would rather have something like this:

```
/specialty/project_management
```

How do I replace the spaces with underscores and still look up the correct model in the controller action? Any side notes on security also appreciated

Comment: Is there an example of your view or helper code where are you using `url_for` ? We need to see this to see how you are generating these paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **to_param**:

**Model:**

```
class Specialty < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
   name.parameterize
  end
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def specialty
    @specialty = Specialty.find(params[:id])
end
```

That should do it...

References:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#to-param
- https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @manishie is good, but there is also a gem that handles this for you (and much more), called [Friendly ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It is based on the same `to_param` trick as previously mentioned, but also has options to handle other special characters and handle collisions.

```
class Specialty < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name
end

Specialty.friendly.find(params[:name])
```